# How to modify type slice inside method?

Tags: go, slice

How to modify type slice inside method? I tried 
http://play.golang.org/p/ul2n8mk6ye

```
type Test []string

func (test Test) Add(str string) {
    test = append(test, str)
}

func main() {
    test := Test{}
    test.Add("value")
    fmt.Println(len(test))//0
}
```

And http://play.golang.org/p/nV9IO7E5sp

```
type Test []string

func (test *Test) Add(str string) {
    v := append(*test, str)
    test = &v
}

func main() {
        test := Test{}
    test.Add("value")
    fmt.Println(len(test))//0
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a pointer receiver, which you've tried in your second example, but you then overwrite the pointer value which defeats the purpose.

You could use

```
func (test *Test) Add(str string) {
    v := append(*test, str)
    *test = v
}
```

Or more clearly:

```
func (test *Test) Add(str string) {
    *test = append(*test, str)
}
```